# Changing Dropdown Icon on Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

On Bootstrap 3 this was pretty easy, you just had to change span and add whatever icon you wanted instead. But that doesn't seem the case with Bootstrap 4. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Anyway, here's the basic code for it:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me if it's possible to change the dropdown icon on this and how? I want to add one from fontawesome.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2023)**

Changing the dropdown caret to an icon still works the same way in Bootstrap 5. Don't forget to change the `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/oG5SpGwWfL

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

You have to hide the caret icon like this..

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add the fontawesome icon..

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

https://codeply.com/p/BV8WjfEPzb

***OR***, just remove the `dropdown-toggle` class from the button as it's only purpose seems to be showing the caret icon.

Comment: display:none is a better solution since if you remove dropdown-toggle class then nested dropdowns (dropdown inside dropdown) won't work.

Comment: How do I override the default one with another?

Answer (score 11):

The default caret isn't an icon, rather a border with these properties:

```
border-top: .3em solid;
border-right: .3em solid transparent;
border-bottom: 0;
border-left: .3em solid transparent;
```

Thus if you set `.dropdown-toggle::after` to have `border:none!important`, you can the use `content` to set the icon you want.

The code I use is this:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  border: none!important;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f107"!important; /* the desired FontAwesome icon */
  vertical-align: 0; /* to center vertically */
}
```

With this method you can also change the FontAwesome icon when the dropdown is visible, thanks to the .show class it adds:

```
li.menu-item.show a.dropdown-toggle.::after {
  content: "\f106"!important /* the different icon */
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I've done something similar to the accepted answer, changing the default caret to a vertical ellipsis from font-awesome like this:

```
.dropdown-toggle-ellipsis::after {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle-ellipsis::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f142";
}
```

Just apply `dropdown-toggle-ellipsis` as an additional class to your toggle button.

The main difference with this solution is that the actual icon (`\f142` here) is now defined in your stylesheets, not in your markup. Whether that's a plus depends on your situation of course.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that allows to keep the HTML as it is and simply adding one CSS rule:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  border: none;
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: "\f078";
  vertical-align: 0;
}
```

This will work with Font Awesome 5. The content property can be set to any available Unicode values. For example for the chevron-down (https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-down?style=solid) it's f078.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else arrives via a google search for how to insert the dropdown icon, here's a nice way:

```
<span style="color:black;" class="fa fa-caret-down pl-1"></span>
```

This uses font awesome 5, and the `pl-1` adds a little padding to the left of the dropdown icon so it's more nicely spaced.

The result is an icon very similar to that found on GitHub:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestions in the other answers, I added rules in my app's main CSS file for the the dropdown-toggle.

The key is that Bootstrap adds the "collapsed" class to items with "dropdown-toggle" when the content is hidden and removes the class when the content is displayed.

```css
/* Align Bootstrap default Dropdown icon closer to vertical center of collapsed icon. */
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    vertical-align: 0.15em;
}

/* Make Dropdown icon point right when collapsed, with Browser default vertical alignment. */
.collapsed.dropdown-toggle::after {
    border-top: 0.3em solid transparent;
    border-left: 0.3em solid;
    border-bottom: 0.3em solid transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    vertical-align: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are NOT using font-awesome, you can simple use the `url()` CSS function and drop the SVG code directly into the CSS:

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after{
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.0.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M192 384c-8.188 0-16.38-3.125-22.62-9.375l-160-160c-12.5-12.5-12.5-32.75 0-45.25s32.75-12.5 45.25 0L192 306.8l137.4-137.4c12.5-12.5 32.75-12.5 45.25 0s12.5 32.75 0 45.25l-160 160C208.4 380.9 200.2 384 192 384z"/></svg>');
  border: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0.4rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can download whichever SVG you would like from font awesome: https://fontawesome.com/search?s=solid

Answer (score 0):

Just type in css border none. The arrow is made from borders, if you remove the borders then there is no arrow. After you remove the border you can add your own icons.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after{
 border: none;
 content: '\icon';
}
```