# How to replace Bootstrap dropdown-toggle icon with another default icon?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a pure CSS method to replace the caret icon in Bootstrap's `dropdown-toggle` class? I want it to look like a downward arrowhead or logical-or symbol (`&or;`), like this:

[image: dropdown with arrow]

instead of the original downward solid triangle caret. I've found answers for replacing the size of the original icon:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block; /* Default */
    width: 0; /* Default */
    height: 0; /* Default */
    margin-left: .3em; /* Default */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Default */
    content: ""; /* Default */
    border-top: .3em solid; /* caret size */
    border-right: .3em solid transparent; /* caret size */
    border-left: .3em solid transparent; /* caret size */
}
```

but I can't figure out a good way to make it an arrowhead. Another question referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233421/changing-dropdown-icon-on-bootstrap-4) requires you to manually embed the image in HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might change the default values to the following:

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  font: 400 1.5rem/1.25 sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: purple;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: .3em;
  height: .3em;
  margin: -.3em 0 0 .4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border: .3em solid;
  border-width: 0 .15em .15em 0;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg)
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdown-toggle">CUSTOMERS</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

As described in this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233421/changing-dropdown-icon-on-bootstrap-4#43233547), you can either just remove the current icon and use a `<span>` or `<i>` tag to add your own custom/Font Awesome icon like this:

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
        display: none !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: #7c2a8b;">
    Customer
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can skip the css part and just remove the `dropdown-toggle` class name and add the icon to your html like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: #7c2a8b;">
    Customer
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the add icon that you want inside the `span` tag.

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
      <span>+</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `FontAwesome`

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}



.dropdown-toggle:after {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f107";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="dropdown-toggle">CUSTOMERS</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<button style="font-size:24px">CUSTOMERS <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>

</body>
</html>
```

code here:http://jsfiddle.net/06ngr298/

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there was a caret in FontAwesome, thanks for sharing - this was my 2nd favorite answer, Kosh's seems more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents :) `aria-labelledby`, `attr.aria-labelledby` - to have correct connection between a toggler and its popup, `[class.dropdown-toggle]="false"` - to hide standard icon, `aria-haspopup="true"` - to keep popup working when clicking `ngbDropdownToggle` element. And decorate this element in the way you want.

```
<div class="ellipsis" ngbDropdown container="body" placement="bottom">
          <i
            class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"
            ngbDropdownToggle
            aria-haspopup="true"
            [class.dropdown-toggle]="false"
            id="{{ 'nodeAction_' + node.key }}"
          ></i>
          <div
            class="dropdown-menu"
            ngbDropdownMenu
            attr.aria-labelledby="{{ 'nodeAction_' + node.key }}"
          >
            <li
              class="dropdown-item pointer"
              ngbDropdownItem
              (click)="onEdit(node.origin.entity.tenant)"
            >
              {{ 'AbpIdentity::Edit' | abpLocalization }}
            </li>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

if someone still need help about just change button with image and then change icon with src property:

```html
<div className="btn-group shadow-0 dropdown">
  <img className="dropdown-toggle my-auto" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" src={icons.ic_setting}/>
  
  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
    <ListItemWithImage icon={icons.ic_setting} label={t('settings')}/>
    <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```